# Seaborn PairGrid: show axes tick-labels for each subplot

Tags: grid-layout, seaborn

With `seaborn.PairGrid` is there a way to show the axes tick-labels for each subplot? (an equivalent to `sharex=False, sharey=False` in case of `seaborn.FacetGrid`)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame()
for n in ['a', 'b']:
    tmp = pd.DataFrame({'name': [n] * 100,
                        'prior': [1, 10] * 50,
                        'post': [1, 10] * 50})
    df = df.append(tmp)

g = sns.PairGrid(df, hue='name', diag_sharey=False)
g.map_offdiag(sns.regplot, fit_reg=False, x_jitter=.1)
g.map_diag(sns.distplot, kde=False)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer found here: [Show y_ticklabels in a seaborn pairplot with shared axes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31094436/show-y-ticklabels-in-a-seaborn-pairplot)

```
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    _ = plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), visible=True)
    _ = plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), visible=True)
```

Where it is precised that `_ = ...` is here to suppress unwanted print out in interactive environments.

Comment: Getting this error in PairGrid : ```AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_yticklabels'``` Any suggestions or am I 5 yrs too late :D?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried set a style with `sns.set_style("ticks")` ?

More details about controlling figure aesthetics:
http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/aesthetics.html

Comment: I edited my question to clarify: I meant the axes tick-labels. They are only displayed on the main plot axes. I want them on each subplot.

Answer (score 0):

I would call `.set` on the pairplot `PairGrid`

```
g = sns.pairplot(...)
g.set(xticklabels=[], yticklabels=[])
```