# Seaborn PairGrid - how to add x,y labels in all subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, pairgrid

I'm having a hard time renaming the subplots axis in a Seaborn.PairGrid plot.
[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33377243/seaborn-pairgrid-show-axes-labels-for-each-subplot) was the main post I was following to try to solve my issue but for me it simply does not work. I have also tried with `df.axes[i,j].set(ylabel='foo', xlabel='bar')`
as some other post suggested but it also does not work with the inner subplots, they still don't display the axis labels. The result I want is just like what `tmdavison` showed but I believe things might have changed slightly over the years due to package updates (since his answer is 6yo+).

This issue I'm having is very similar to this one reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64345086/adding-axis-to-all-boxes-in-seaborn-pairplots).

I even tried increasing the space between the subplots and ensuring both axis were enable but that also didn't make any difference.

```
for ax in g.axes.flat:
  ax.tick_params(axis='both', labelleft=True, labelbottom=True)

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.7, hspace=0.3)
```

My full code based on the other post I mentioned:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")

g = sns.PairGrid(iris)
g = g.map(plt.scatter)

for ax in g.axes.flat:
  ax.tick_params(axis='both', labelleft=True, labelbottom=True)

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.7, hspace=0.3)

xlabels,ylabels = [],[]

for ax in g.axes[-1,:]:
  xlabel = ax.xaxis.get_label_text()
  xlabels.append(xlabel)
for ax in g.axes[:,0]:
  ylabel = ax.yaxis.get_label_text()
  ylabels.append(ylabel)

for i in range(len(xlabels)):
  for j in range(len(ylabels)):
    g.axes[j,i].xaxis.set_label_text(xlabels[i])
    g.axes[j,i].yaxis.set_label_text(ylabels[j])

plt.show()
```

Result:

[image: Running the above code gives me:]

Versions I'm running:
Python: 3.10.1; Seaborn: 0.12.0; Matplotlib: 3.6.1

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem by posting this issue at Seaborn's GitHub page and I wanted to post here for future reference.
Indirectly quoting [the dev](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/discussions/3094) in his reply, `visible=True` is the part this code is missing. So by simply changing

```
g.axes[j,i].xaxis.set_label_text(xlabels[i], visible=True)
g.axes[j,i].yaxis.set_label_text(ylabels[j], visible=True)
```

The above code should work as intended!
[image: s]